# Library conflicts between Openssl and NMSSH

Tags: installation, openssl, cocoapods, mqtt, nmssh

I am developing an app in swiftui that needs to connect to a remote computer to download some files. I read that NMSSH was a good way to doing that in IOS apps. Now the problem is that I also connect to a mqtt broker using moscapsule and openssl, and when I try to install both openssl-universal and NMSSH using "pod install", installation fails.
The error message is the following:

"The 'Pods-MyApp' target has libraries with conflicting names: libssl.a and libcrypto.a."

I guess the problem is that both openssl and NMSSH are using the same libraries and Xcode doesn't like it.

I am a new to Xcode and swiftui development, so I haven't been able to find a solution to that issue...
Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there are conflicting libraries. I guess that OpenSSL was somehow already initialized, and the crash happens because OpenSSL does not support being initialized twice. Try removing **use_frameworks!** from your podfile that should fix the issue. You can manually delete the OpenSSL headers from NMSSH, they are not required. Otherwise you can import NMSSH manually.

Similar issue was faced by an user: https://github.com/NMSSH/NMSSH/issues/142

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70310469/edit) your answer rather than adding extra information via comments